# hollow a region with cylinders/tubes

Tags: 3d-printing, stl-format

I am new to Mathematica. And I am working on building a stl format model.

I am able to build an array for my cylinders, which is using the Graphics3D.

[image]

I want to put this array inside a cube and hollow out these regions. How can I do this? I tried to do it using BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics. However, it is not rendering the correct model. Somehow the middle part of the array (which is the bending part) is missing from the model. I use a smaller 2x2 array to test. Only the top and bottom cylinders are there. The Spheres or the middle cylinder are not.

My code

```
radius = 2.5;inpitch = 6;outpitch = 25;firstsegment = 100;angle = 10;totalheight = 1000;cube = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {100, 100, totalheight}];a = 2;b = 2;
c = Table[Random[], {n, 1, a}, {m, 1, b}];
cy1 = Sphere1 = cy2 = Sphere2 = cy3 = reg = reg1 = reg2 = reg3 = reg4 = reg5 = c;
Do[cy1[[i, j]] =  Cylinder[{{(i - 0.5)*inpitch, (j - 0.5)*inpitch,0}, {(i - 0.5)*inpitch, (j - 0.5)*inpitch, firstsegment}}, radius];Sphere1[[i, j]] = Sphere[{(i - 0.5)*inpitch, (j - 0.5)*inpitch, firstsegment}, radius]; cy2[[i, j]] = Cylinder[{{(i - 0.5)*inpitch, (j - 0.5)*inpitch, firstsegment}, {(i - 0.5)*outpitch, (j - 0.5)*outpitch, firstsegment + Sqrt[((i - 0.5)*(outpitch - inpitch))^2 + ((j - 0.5)*(outpitch -inpitch))^2]/N[Tan[angle]]}}, radius]; Sphere2[[i, j]] = Sphere[{(i - 0.5)*outpitch, (j - 0.5)*outpitch, firstsegment + Sqrt[((i - 0.5)*(outpitch - inpitch))^2 + ((j - 0.5)*(outpitch - inpitch))^2]/N[Tan[angle]]}, radius]; Print[cy3[[i, j]] =Cylinder[{{(i - 0.5)*outpitch, (j - 0.5)*outpitch, firstsegment + Sqrt[((i - 0.5)*(outpitch - inpitch))^2 + ((j -0.5)*(outpitch - inpitch))^2]/N[Tan[angle]]}, {(i - 0.5)*outpitch, (j - 0.5)*outpitch, totalheight}}, radius]], {i, 1, a}, {j, 1, b}]

Do[reg1[[i, j]] = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[cy1[[i, j]], MaxCellMeasure -> 10];reg2[[i, j]] = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[cy3[[i, j]], MaxCellMeasure -> 10];reg3[[i, j]] = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Sphere1[[i, j]], MaxCellMeasure -> 10];reg4[[i, j]] =BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Sphere2[[i, j]], MaxCellMeasure -> 10];reg5[[i, j]] = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[cy2[[i, j]], MaxCellMeasure -> 10];reg[[i, j]] = RegionUnion[reg5[[i, j]]];t1 = RegionDifference[t0, reg1[[i, j]]];t0 = t1,{i, 1, a}, {j, 1, b}]

a = Graphics3D[{cy1, cy2, cy3, Sphere1, Sphere2}];Export["graph.stl", a];Import["graph.stl"]

Export["fiber.stl", t0];Import["fiber.stl"]
```

I only put the top part in the RegionUnion so that it runs. If I also put the middle part, it seems to take forever.

[image]

I wonder if there is another way to do this and render the model correctly in stl with reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Sure. Already did that.

Comment: Try to use the OpenCascadeLink.